# Windows .NET on PC send/receive files from Android phone o0ver Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project that requires a Windows application running on a desktop/laptop PC with Bluetooth to talk to an Android phone to share files.  I want to be able to get a file from the PC to the phone and from the phone to the PC.  It can be done through a send on both or a send/receive from either one.

I'm working in .NET on the PC and either Android Studio or Xamarin (Visual Studio) on the Android phone.

I've looked at the 32feet SDK's, and I can send a file from the PC with OBEX, but I'm forced to accept the file on the Android phone.  I'd like to send a file and either either put it in a directory on the phone or handle it manually in my code on the phone with some sort of receiver in Android.

I'm writing both applications ... native phone app and Windows application.

What I'd really love to do is some sort of shared directory on the phone.  Phone app writes to a particular directory on the phone.  PC polls that directory over Bluetooth and removes files from the directory when read.  PC application then writes files to that directory on the phone for the phone app to poll/read for.

Any examples of something similar?  Or something that will help me accomplish this task?

.......

I'm seeing the downvotes ... here's some code I'm using to send a file to the phone.  I need to know how to accept this automatically with a receiver on the phone and write the file to disk on the phone...

```
Private Sub btnTestBeam1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestBeam1.Click

    Dim sbdd As New InTheHand.Windows.Forms.SelectBluetoothDeviceDialog
    Dim ofdFileToBeam As New OpenFileDialog
    sbdd.ShowAuthenticated = True
    sbdd.ShowRemembered = True
    sbdd.ShowUnknown = True

    If sbdd.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        If ofdFileToBeam.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim theuri As New Uri("obex://" + sbdd.SelectedDevice.DeviceAddress.ToString() + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofdFileToBeam.FileName))
            Dim request As New ObexWebRequest(theuri)
            request.ReadFile(ofdFileToBeam.FileName)

            Dim response As ObexWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), ObexWebResponse)
            MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString())
            response.Close()

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

What I'm looking for is the ability to write straight to a folder on the phone or how to receive the file with an app on the phone.

And I also need to be able to do the same from the phone back to the PC..

Any comments/suggestions would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help any in posterity ...

PC side of things ....

```
Dim connectserver As Thread
Dim mstream As Stream
Dim client As BluetoothClient
Dim bluelisten As BluetoothListener
Dim muuid As Guid = New Guid("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66")
Dim serverstart As Boolean = False

Private Sub btnTestb1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestb1.Click
    If (serverstart) Then
        updateui("server already started")
    End If

    connectasserver()
End Sub

Private Sub connectasserver()
    connectserver = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf serverconnectedthread))
    connectserver.Start()
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub SetText(text As String)

Private Sub updateui(mess As String)
    If LabelTestb.InvokeRequired Then
        LabelTestb.Invoke(New SetText(AddressOf updateui), mess)
    Else
        LabelTestb.Text = mess & vbCrLf & LabelTestb.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub serverconnectedthread()
    Dim sent() As Byte
    Dim recieved(1024) As Byte

    serverstart = True
    updateui("waiting for connections of clients\n")
    bluelisten = New BluetoothListener(muuid)
    bluelisten.Start()
    client = New BluetoothClient()
    client = bluelisten.AcceptBluetoothClient()
    updateui("client has connected\n")
    mstream = client.GetStream()

    While (True)
        Try
            mstream.Read(recieved, 0, recieved.Length)

            updateui("recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieved))
            sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" hello world\n")
            mstream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length)
            sent = Nothing
        Catch except As IOException

            updateui("client has been disconnected\n")
            connectserver.Abort()
            client.Close()
            mstream.Flush()
        End Try
    End While

End Sub
```

Android side of things....
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat

Given those two sides ... I will be able to transfer bytes over the line in both directions exactly like I want.